# Installation of dependencies of R packages from local repository

Tags: r, packrat

Has the issue described here been resolved:
https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/169

If not, does it mean that if I have a package [package_from_local_repo] installed by packrat from a local repository, its dependencies (although available in CRAN, etc) will not be installed?

Is a workaround to use library([missing dependency]) on the same R code that calls my [package_from_local_repo]?

Comment: Probable not (yet) for the CRAN version since it is set as a version 0.5 milestone in the github issues that you linked. Maybe it has been resolved in the latest github version. Try asking @KevinUshey in a comment in the github issue that you linked?